# Calculate duration of the memory game and send it to the database

Tags: c#, javascript, sql, asp.net

I need to calculate a total duration of the memory game. At the moment I can count the clicks, but I need to figure out how long it takes to open all images in sec. How can I send it to the database? I've tried some code but with no luck. This is my first experience with JavaScript, so please forgive me if the answer is obvious. Thanks for any advice.

**Update**: @Pieter21 Unfortunately it didn't work. I got an error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. At the moment "Duration" is a Timestamp in my localDB. 
Javascript :

```
    <script>
    var BoxOpened = "";
    var ImageOpened = "";
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var Counter = 0;
    var ImageFound = 0;


    var Source = "#memorybox";

    var ImageSource = [
      "Images/animals/cow.jpg",
      "Images/animals/cow2.jpg",
      "Images/animals/sheep.jpg",
      "Images/food/lemon.jpg",
      "Images/animals/elephant.jpg",
      "Images/animals/giraffe.jpg",
      "Images/food/banana.jpg",
      "Images/animals/dog.jpg",
      "Images/animals/horse.jpg",
      "Images/animals/lion.jpg"
    ];



        function RandomFunction(MaxValue, MinValue) {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * (MaxValue - MinValue) + MinValue);
    }

    function ShuffleImages() {
        var ImageAll = $(Source).children();
        var ImageThis = $(Source + " div:first-child");
        var ImageArr = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i < ImageAll.length; i++) {
            ImageArr[i] = $("#" + ImageThis.attr("id") + " img").attr("src");
            ImageThis = ImageThis.next();
        }

        ImageThis = $(Source + " div:first-child");

        for (var z = 0; z < ImgageAll.length; z++) {
            var RandomNumber = RandomFunction(0, ImgArr.length - 1);

            $("#" + ImageThis.attr("id") + " img").attr("src", ImageArr[RandomNumber]);
            ImageArr.splice(RandomNumber, 1);
            ImageThis = ImageThis.next();
        }
    }

    function ResetGame() {
        ShuffleImages();
        $(Source + " div img").hide();
        $(Source + " div").css("visibility", "visible");
        Counter = 0;
        $("#success").remove();
        $("#counter").html("" + Counter);
        BoxOpened = "";
        ImageOpened = "";
        ImageFound = 0;
        return false;
    }

    function OpenCard() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        if ($("#" + id + " img").is(":hidden")) {
            $(Source + " div").unbind("click", OpenCard);

            $("#" + id + " img").slideDown('fast');

            if (ImageOpened == "") {
                BoxOpened = id;
                ImageOpened = $("#" + id + " img").attr("src");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(Source + " div").bind("click", OpenCard)
                }, 300);
            } else {
                CurrentOpened = $("#" + id + " img").attr("src");
                if (ImageOpened != CurrentOpened) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#" + id + " img").slideUp('fast');
                        $("#" + BoxOpened + " img").slideUp('fast');
                        BoxOpened = "";
                        ImageOpened = "";
                    }, 400);
                } else {
                    $("#" + id + " img").parent().css("visibility", "hidden");
                    $("#" + BoxOpened + " img").parent().css("visibility", "hidden");
                    ImageFound++;
                    BoxOpened = "";
                    ImageOpened = "";
                }
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(Source + " div").bind("click", OpenCard)
                }, 400);
            }
            Counter++;
            $("#<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>").val(Counter);


            $("#counter").html("" + Counter);




            if (ImageFound == ImageSource.length) {
                $("#counter").prepend('<span id="success" runat="server">You Found All Pictues With </span>');

                setTimeout(function () {
                    var endTime = new Date().getTime();
                    console.log("duration  = " + (endTime - startTime));
                }, 1500);

                //$("#HiddenField2").html("" + (endTime - startTime));
                //alert(endTime - startTime);
                $("#<%=HiddenField2.ClientID%>").val(endTime - startTime);

            }
        }
    }

    $(function () {

        for (var y = 1; y < 3 ; y++) {
            $.each(ImageSource, function (i, val) {
                $(Source).append("<div id=card" + y + i + "><img src=" + val + " />");
            });
        }
        $(Source + " div").click(OpenCard);
        ShuffleImages();

    });
```

HTML :

```
<span id="Span1" class="button" runat="server">

    <span id="counter"   >0 </span>
  Clicks  </span> 

  <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"    />
  <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" />



<span class="button">

  <a onclick="ResetGame();">Reset</a>

</span> 

  <asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click"  CssClass="button" />
```

C# :

```
    SqlConnection connection = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }
    }


   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int value = int.Parse(HiddenField1.Value);
    DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(HiddenField2.Value);

    connection = DatabaseConnectionSetup();
    SqlCommand submitCommand;
    try
    {
        submitCommand = new SqlCommand("ResultInsert", connection);
        submitCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      submitCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Duration", HiddenField2.Value);
        submitCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserScore", HiddenField1.Value);

        connection.Open();
        submitCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }


}

private SqlConnection DatabaseConnectionSetup()
{

    try
    {
        ConnectionStringSettings connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MonkeyClubConnectionString"];
        if (connectionString != null)
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return connection;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have much to do with SQL.  Can you remove the tag?

Comment: Possibly it is still SQL, at least half of it, to calculate a javascript timespan and convert it into valid SQL data.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the game length calculations only on the client side.

I think you already show some intentions to store it in a "hidden field 2", but you don't follow through. Uncomment the field in ASP.NET, fill it with Javascipt in the javascript, and copy it in the C# codebehind.

You also have to make sure that what you store in the field can be recognized as a datetime in SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hints- I commented out my hidden field, filled it witj Javascript:    setTimeout(function () {
                        var endTime = new Date().getTime();
                        console.log("duration  = " + (endTime - startTime));
                    }, 1500);

                    //$("#HiddenField2").html("" + (endTime - startTime));
                    //alert(endTime - startTime);
                    $("#<%=HiddenField2.ClientID%>").val(endTime - startTime);

Comment: But did it work? If so, please mark as an answer to make it clear.

If not please make those changes to the original post and mention that it still does not work.

Also, if it still doesn't work, it is likely that your endTime-startTime is a timeSpan that may not match your table column type of a timestamp.